# Why does my mongodb query do not return anything?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

/*   I'm new in MongoDB and trying to figure out how to get the average `correct_answers` for course CSIS2300.

```
There is a part of the document. Some users take more than one course */


      {
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "user_id" : "jjackson0",
    "first_name" : "Jack",
    "last_name" : "Jackson",
    "email" : "jjackson0@apache.org",
    "status" : "active",
    "join_date" : "2014-12-10",
    "last_login_date" : "2016-09-30 23:51:41 -0400",
    "strengths" : [ 
        "mongo queries", 
        "mongo map-reduce queries"
    ],
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS2300",
            "total_questions" : 165.0,
            "correct_answers" : 153.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 12.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "user_id" : "ecoleman1",
    "first_name" : "Eugene",
    "last_name" : "Coleman",
    "email" : "ecoleman1@techcrunch.com",
    "age" : 49.0,
    "status" : "banned",
    "join_date" : "2015-07-01",
    "last_login_date" : "2016-09-30 23:54:08 -0400",
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Chencun",
        "province" : "PEI"
    },
    "strengths" : [ 
        "visualization", 
        "sql", 
        "query optimisation", 
        "dimensional modelling", 
        "analytics research"
    ],
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS2300",
            "total_questions" : 188.0,
            "correct_answers" : 106.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 82.0
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS3300",
            "total_questions" : 12.0,
            "correct_answers" : 9.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS3380",
            "total_questions" : 172.0,
            "correct_answers" : 142.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 30.0
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS3360",
            "total_questions" : 140.0,
            "correct_answers" : 21.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 119.0
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS4260",
            "total_questions" : 163.0,
            "correct_answers" : 75.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 88.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "user_id" : "mbowman2",
    "first_name" : "Mark",
    "last_name" : "Bowman",
    "email" : "mbowman2@ebay.co.uk",
    "age" : 36.0,
    "status" : "disabled",
    "join_date" : "2015-02-01",
    "last_login_date" : "2016-09-30 23:58:07 -0400",
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Ban Kruat",
        "province" : "NL"
    },
    "strengths" : [ 
        "mongo map-reduce queries", 
        "sql", 
        "dimensional modelling", 
        "visualization"
    ],
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS2300",
            "total_questions" : 185.0,
            "correct_answers" : 171.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 14.0
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS3300",
            "total_questions" : 57.0,
            "correct_answers" : 54.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 3.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4.0,
    "user_id" : "acollins3",
    "first_name" : "Andrew",
    "last_name" : "Collins",
    "email" : "acollins3@unesco.org",
    "status" : "inactive",
    "join_date" : "2016-03-06",
    "last_login_date" : "2016-09-30 23:59:05 -0400",
    "strengths" : [ 
        "analytics research", 
        "mongo queries", 
        "normalization"
    ],
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS2300",
            "total_questions" : 101.0,
            "correct_answers" : 37.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 64.0
        }
    ]
}
```

There is my query which does not return anything.

```
    db.assign1.aggregate([
            {$project: 
                {_id: 0,
                 course_code: "$courses.code",
                 correctAns: {$max: "$courses.correct_answers"}}},
            {$match: {"courses.code": "CSIS2300"}},
            {$group: {_id: {"code": "$courses.code"}, Average_CorrectAns: {$avg: "$courses.correct_answers"}}}

            ]);
```

Comment: try to use $unwind instead of the $project stage

Comment: I used $unwind on "courses" and I got results but I'm still not sure if I've responded correctly to the question.

Comment: Well only you can tell since we don't have the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your **$project** stage changes **$courses.code** to **course_code**, so after this stage there is no field with that name (same is true for **$courses.correct_answers**). In addition, usually it's better to **$match** first as it improves performance of your query. Further, you can add stages to a query one by one and run it each time to see what output you get after each stage.

To find average you need to $unwind the **courses** array, the final query as follows:

```
db.assign1.aggregate([{$unwind: "$courses"},
                      {$match: {"courses.code": "CSIS2300"}},
                      {$group: {_id: {"code": "$courses.code"}, correctAns: {$avg: "$courses.correct_answers"}}},
                      {$project: {course_Code: "$_id.code", correctAns: 1, _id: 0}}
                     ]);
```

Comment: I used **course_code** to **$match** instead of **$courses.code**. I worked well but now I get _null_ for the average :(

Comment: @Cyrille Give an example of a whole document in your question.

Comment: @Cyrille Or at least modify the existing example so there are several elements in the arrays.

Comment: I just added more data. Some users take more than one course.

Comment: @Cyrille I've modified my answer.

Comment: I've tried again and it worked out even without **$project**. Thank you so much for your help :) @Andriy